# Why there are two ifcfg-eth0 file but in different directory

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I am trying to understand why there are 3 ifcfg-eth0 on my CentOS 6.4 server, they are hardlinks to the same file looks like.

Anyone knows why ?

```
$ ll /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
-rw-r--r--. **3** root root 166 Jul 31  2012 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

$ find / -type f -name ifcfg-eth0 -exec openssl dgst -md5 {} \;
MD5(/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0)= **c5cd670606e1feb78752a9644f021c1f**
MD5(/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0)= **c5cd670606e1feb78752a9644f021c1f**
MD5(/etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default/ifcfg-eth0)= **c5cd670606e1feb78752a9644f021c1f**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 2 RPMs

The files are remnants of 2 RPM packages. If you run the following command you can see which RPMs are responsible for these directories:

```
# centos 6.4
$ for i in /etc/sysconfig/networking /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts; do echo "==> $i"; rpm -qf $i;done
==> /etc/sysconfig/networking
system-config-network-tui-1.6.0.el6.2-1.el6.noarch
initscripts-9.03.31-2.el6.centos.1.x86_64
==> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
initscripts-9.03.31-2.el6.centos.1.x86_64
```

The 2 RPMs are pretty old, I have an ancient Fedora Core 3 system that has these 2 directories as being owned by `initscripts`, so that looks to be the original owner.

```
# fedora core 3
$ rpm -qf /etc/sysconfig/networking /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
initscripts-7.93.7-1
initscripts-7.93.7-1
```

At some point the configuration files for the tool, `system-config-network` expanded into these directories as well:

```
# centos 6.4
$ rpm -ql system-config-network-tui-1.6.0.el6.2-1.el6.noarch|grep "^/etc/.*/network.*"
/etc/sysconfig/networking
/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices
/etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles
/etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles/default
```

#### GUI's that use above directories

Incidentally the GUIs can equally be confusing but there is really just a single one that detects whether it was called in a X environment or in a terminal and displays the appropriate "GUI" for the given environment.

```
$ more /usr/sbin/system-config-network
#!/bin/sh

if [ -n "$DISPLAY" -a -f /usr/sbin/system-config-network-gui ]; then
    exec /usr/sbin/system-config-network-gui "$@"
else
    exec /usr/sbin/system-config-network-tui "$@"
```

**system-config-network-gui**

[image: ss of gui]

**system-config-network-tui**

[image: ss of tui]

[image: ss of profiles]

[image: ss of one profile]

**NOTE:** The tui version and the gui version of the GUI both have this notion of "profiles" and "devices" with which this information is kept in the directories `/etc/sysconfig/networking/*`.

#### What about ifcfg-* files?

So what we're left with is a confusing pile of fun. The following service and scripts depend on the `ifcfg-*` files, which are really key to network management on a Red Hat box:

- The network service `/etc/init.d/network`
- The up script `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup`
- The down script `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifdown`

#### So what about the GUIs?

1. The GUIs mentioned above are really antiques, they do still work, but in general if you're not using NetworkManager, it's probably easier in the long run to just manage the information for network configurations directly by managing the files under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*`.
2. Unless you're doing basic types of network configurations some of the features/capabilities available to you when setting up a network may not be accessible through the tui/gui so really `NetworkManager` or the `ifcfg-*` files are the best options.
3. The tui/gui tools end up just writing data into `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` through the links you originally asked about, so you might as well just edit the files directly.

Answer (score 1):

Before `NetworkManager` was a thing, Red Hat had (I'm guessing still has from your output, I have the directories but no files in them on the two servers I checked) a `sysconfig-*` tool you could use to specify which networking profile to use, after which you just restart the `network` service and the other settings take effect.

Last one in the `find` output is the ifcfg for the `default` profile, the top one is where the `network` service actually looks, and `devices` I've never had to mess with so I don't know what part of the sysconfig process they're supposed to serve, but if it's under `networking` it's all part of that scheme. This is something that is exceedingly old and not likely to be relevant now that NM handles network configurations on machines that move around to different networks on a regular basis (like laptops) fairly well.

**EDIT:**
[Here](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2010-November/101701.html) is another description of the same thing from the CentOS mailing list.